# Get selected value from <g:select dropdown

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I'm trying to get 2 chained dropdown lists. First one is showing remote server folders, and after choosing, 2-nd one is showing files in selected folder. Next I want to copy chosen file to my local disk. But I'm unable to get file name into some variable to use it later. And this list is rendered from controller, not from gsp. Followed this link: http://grails.asia/grails-chained-select---load-data-on-one-dropdown-box-depending-on-another.
   Dropdown lists are rendered fine, but the problem is that I need to get value, selected from 2-nd dropdown list (file names), to the controller, and use it in future. Please help me with this problem.
Domain class:

```html
package filemanager

class SourceServ {
 String sourceServName
 String sourceServFolder
 int sourceServPort
 String sourceServUser
 String sourceServPassword
 String localFolder
 Boolean selected
 static hasMany = [destservs: DestServ]
    static constraints = {
  sourceServName blank: false, nullable: false
  sourceServFolder blank: false, nullable: false
  sourceServPort blank: false, nullable: false
  sourceServUser blank: false, nullable: false
  sourceServPassword blank: false, nullable: false
  localFolder blank: false, nullable: false
  selected nullable: true
    }
 
static mapping = {
        destservs cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
}
```

Controller:

```html
package filemanager
import com.jcraft.jsch.*
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.*

class ChooseFromController {
 SourceServ sourceServ
 DestServ destServ
 String value
 String fileName
 String name
    def index(Integer max)   {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
  model:[sourceServ: SourceServ]
    }
 //Вывод второго списка с файлами
 def sourceServChanged(long sourceServId) { 
  sourceServ = SourceServ.get(sourceServId)
  FileWork fileWork1 = new FileWork (sourceServ.getSourceServName(), sourceServ.getSourceServUser(), sourceServ.getSourceServPassword(), sourceServ.getSourceServFolder(), "C:/tmp/", sourceServ.getSourceServPort(), "null")
  Session ses
  ses = fileWork1.connect()
  def fileList = fileWork1.getFileList(ses) 
  ses.disconnect()
  render g.select(name:'fileName', 
      from:fileList, noSelection:[null:'-Choose file to copy-'])
      //onchange:getFileName(this.value))
  render fileName
 }
 def getFileName(input){
  render "Hello" //input //fileName
 }
 def copyToLocal(String x) {
  render fileName//sourceServ.getSourceServName()
 }
}
```

GSP:

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" import="filemanager.SourceServ" import="filemanager.DestServ"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>Выбор исходного сервера</title>
 <g:javascript library='jquery' />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body">
  <%--Список исходных серверов с составным option value(то, что выводится в списке)--%>
 <b>Выберите исходный сервер и папку</b>
<div>
 <g:select id="id" name="sourceServName" from="${sourceServ.list()}" value="${id}"
      optionKey="id"
             optionValue="${{it.sourceServName+it.sourceServFolder}}" noSelection="['':'-Choose source server-']" 
             onchange="sourceServChanged(this.value);"/> <%--Передача id в sourceServId--%>
</div>
        <div>
            <b>Выберите файл для копирования </b>
            <span id="subContainer"></span>
        </div>
        <script>
            function sourceServChanged(sourceServId) {
                <g:remoteFunction controller="ChooseFrom" action="sourceServChanged"
                 update="subContainer"
                    params="'sourceServId='+sourceServId"/>
            }
        </script>
 </div>   
 <br>    
 <%--<g:submitButton name="copyToLocal" class="button" value="copyToLocal" />--%>   
 <g:form controller="ChooseFrom">
          <g:actionSubmit value="Submit" action="copyToLocal"/>
    </g:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is from your javascript the new select element is rendered in to the span "subContainer" which is outside of the form. try replacing the span tag to be inside the form element

```
<g:form controller="ChooseFrom">
          <span id="subContainer"></span>
          <g:actionSubmit value="Submit" action="copyToLocal"/>
</g:form>
```

Now when the submit button is clicked it submits the values to the copyToLocal action in ChooseFrom Controller. So from inside the action the selected value is accessible from params.fileName